# TzKt not recognising the tokens of my contract

Tags: fa2, fa1.2, tokens, tzkt

TzKt can recognize the FA1.2  and FA2 tokens like this one:
https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1WkGNtcuGq6Rxh8CPSn9J1z7vgxsupBYps/operations/

Here, it understands that it is a token with GaGe as its symbol. And, then also sends it through its API.

But, when I try to deploy my own test [FA1.2 Token](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1JDDJTABTbMrAqL3QdHwqaAam2FBjF9wLq/operations/), it doesn't recognize it. I also added the [contract metadata](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYaiyQe1f8B3Nnw4kRMXchNeJ8WcKA3vog6sijDGhAXMh) and the token metadata as per the standards.
Can anyone help me understand what am I missing here, and how TzKt checks if a smart contract is of a token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** in your particular case the tokens will be recognized after the first `transfer` call.

**Why?** Your contract doesn't fully implement the FA standard (in particular, according to the standard, you must have a ledger bigmap called `%ledger`, but in your contract it's called `%balances`). Therefore, tzkt couldn't recognize it automatically when the contract was originated. However, tzkt is smart enough to try to recognize it later, by analyzing contract's behavior when you do operations with the tokens. So, there is nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Awesome! Now I understand.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is correctly recognized by TzKT. You can see it at the top left, below the contract address it says `financial asset`.

You can also see it by requesting their API, it recognized the contract as being compliant with FA1.2:

```
$ curl https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1JDDJTABTbMrAqL3QdHwqaAam2FBjF9wLq
{... "tzips":["fa12"]...}
```

Comment: Yes, that's good. But, why is it not showing the token information like this...
https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1WkGNtcuGq6Rxh8CPSn9J1z7vgxsupBYps/tokens
https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1JDDJTABTbMrAqL3QdHwqaAam2FBjF9wLq/tokens